# Limit of a sequence $\sqrt[n]{3} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, limits, inequality, convergence-divergence

Using a definition of limit of a sequence and Bernoulli's inequality proof that limit of $\sqrt[n]{3} $ is 1.

From the definition I know that ∀ε>0 ∃N∈ℕ ∀n>N |a<sub>n</sub>-g|<ε and g=1.

|$\sqrt[n]{3}$-1|<ε so that $\sqrt[n]{3}$-1<ε so that $\sqrt[n]{3}$<ε+1 and this is the moment where I got stuck. I know this is the moment where I should use Bernoulli's inequality, but I don't know how. After solving this for n I should prove that |$\sqrt[n]{3}$-1|<ε

Comment: Do you mean $\sqrt[n]{3}$ ?

Comment: Yes, I've allready changed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Use that $(1+\epsilon)^n\ge1+n\epsilon$ by Bernoulli's inequality, and $1+n\epsilon>3 \iff n\epsilon>2\iff n>\frac{2}{\epsilon}$.

Comment: Ok, so now I have |$\sqrt[n]{3}$-1| which is smaller than |$\sqrt[2/ε]{3}$-1| and how can I prove that this is smaller than ε?

Comment: You can use that if $n>\frac{2}{\epsilon}$, then $(1+\epsilon)^n>3\implies 1+\epsilon>\sqrt[n]{3}$.

Answer (score 1):

If you know this theorem, it will be helpful for you.

> If $\lim_{n\to \infty}{x_n}=A$ and $\lim_{n\to \infty}{y_n}=B$, then $\lim_{n\to \infty}{x_n}^{y_n}=A^B$

Comment: I can't use nothing but definition of limit and Bernoulli's inequality.

Answer (score 1):

Set first $\sqrt[n]{3}=1+a_n$; and clearly $a_n>0$. Then 
$$
3=(1+a_n)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}a^k_n< \binom{n}{1}a_n=na_n.
$$
Hence
$$
0<a_n<\frac{3}{n}.\tag{1}
$$
Now, let $\varepsilon>0$ arbritrary. We need to find an $n_0$, such that $n\ge n_0$ implies that $\lvert \sqrt[n]{3}-1\rvert<\varepsilon$. Set
$$
n_0=\left\lfloor\frac{3}{\varepsilon}\right\rfloor+1.
$$
Then
$$
n\ge n_0\quad\Longrightarrow\quad n>\frac{3}{\varepsilon}\quad\Longrightarrow\quad
\varepsilon>\frac{3}{n},\tag{2}
$$
and combining $(1)$ and $(2)$ we obtain
$$
n\ge n_0 \quad\Longrightarrow\quad 0<a_n<\varepsilon,
$$
or
$$
n\ge n_0 \quad\Longrightarrow\quad 0<\sqrt[n]{3}-1<\varepsilon,
$$
and thus
$$
n\ge n_0=\left\lfloor\frac{3}{\varepsilon}\right\rfloor+1 \quad\Longrightarrow\quad \lvert \sqrt[n]{3}-1\rvert <\varepsilon,
$$